# Where to find team stats/comparisons for Eurobasket 2015?

Tags: basketball, statistics

The [Eurobasket 2015 homepage](http://eurobasket2015.org) is a disaster IMHO, although I can find simple information about players, I can't sort players by physical attributes or age etc.

Are there any pages which follow up the championship that have better roster pages? Alternatively is it possible to find the entire list of players (with stats) in raw text which I can play around with in R?

Comment: Source request? See our [help center](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Also, [related meta discussion](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/583/sports-statistics-and-topicality?cb=1)

Comment: @edmastermind29 i dont see how asking for information regarding specific sporting events would be off-topic here on Sports.SE

Comment: @posdef While I agree that this is on topic (per the discussion Ed and I had over at that question), his note is not unreasonable.  "Find this stat for me" is off topic (as this isn't an appropriate site for research requests), and this kind of question ("Where can I find stats on this") was never really discussed on its own.  That's why he linked to the discussion (and asked a question in comments).

Comment: Thanks, @Joe. posdef, you helped write our help center verbiage and in that verbiage, requests for sources/research have been explicitly stated as off-topic for some time. Given Joe's recent discussion on meta, we're looking for to how to deal with this fine line. re: the [meta discussion](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/216/closing-of-my-question-about-finding-a-video-of-a-sporting-event) responsible for the verbiage wrt requests for sources/research, which is ironically wrt a specific sporting event.

Comment: @edmastermind29 interesting meta discussion, I have put my two cents on  the matter under that question.

Answer (score 1):

[EuroBasket](http://www.eurobasket.com/) is a fairly comprehensive site which covers all basketball in Europe, including Eurobasket 2015.

Comment: Can you show what pages would answer the request of the original poster - ie, pages with the rosters that include physical attributes or ages?  I can't find such on that page, for example, with a bit of checking...

Comment: In fact I see rather better information on Eurobasket2015.org, presumably the page the original poster is talking about?

Comment: All of the information is available.  However, for some details you need to be logged in to the site.

Answer (score 0):

This [Eurobasket page](http://www.eurobasket.com/European-Championships/basketball_2015.asp) gives good top level information, and allows you to view stats by team if you go [here](http://www.eurobasket.com/European-Championships/games-schedule.asp?League=1&LName=Div.A&Year=2015). However, there are no sortable stats freely available on the site.

On the [FIBA archive](https://archive.fiba.com/pages/eng/fa/event/p/sID/9322/_/2015_EuroBasket_Final_Round/index.html), there are sortable player stats, however, they do not include information like heights and weights. Same for this [site](http://www.fibaeurope.com/pageID_pRK-RJ6tI8o0CY-VsrxCA0.compID_qMRZdYCZI6EoANOrUf9le2.season_2015.roundID_11664.html).

That's all I have found. You can pay to get historic stats from the Eurobasket site initially linked, but that doesn't answer the question.

Note: There is github code for downloading live stats to analyze in R, but unfortunately not historic ones.

Answer (score -4):

I think that this [link](http://www.sportstats.com/basketball/europe/eurobasket/) can help you a lot and you can find here [the Fiba Europe Stats Suite](http://www.fibaeurope.com/cid_CLnADd0fJ4MZ8xgmecgDF0.html)

Comment: Same as my comment on the other answer: I don't see how either of those provide the information requested by the original poster.  Please link to a specific example page that shows players with their physical attributes in a sortable or scrapable fashion.